# Why is my POST route not found in MERN stack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

i'm currently having two problems with a MERN stack app:

i) Axios was not sending the form body data to the server even when the POST route was working. After each submission, a new entry is made but MongoDB only shows default field values

ii) My POST route was initially working but isn't anymore. Can't seem to hit a POST route now. I get a 404 Not Found error

The webapp has a super basic function to create & list students & their data via a form & table respectively. It uses the material-ui library for component templates

My code:

Server-

```
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()
const app = express()
//ALWAYS use CORS middleware before defining ROUTES!
app.use(cors());
//import routes
import studentRoutes from './routes/student_routes.js'
//middleware to use routes 
app.use('/students' , studentRoutes)

app.use(express.json())
const URI = process.env.DB_URI
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

mongoose.connect(URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then( () => app.listen(port, () => 
console.log(`Listening on Port ${port}`)))
.catch( (err) => console.log(err))
```

Routes-

```
import express from 'express'
import { getStudents } from '../controllers/student_controller.js'
import { createStudent } from "../controllers/student_controller.js";

import Student from '../models/student_model.js'

const router = express.Router()


//list out all students
router.get('/', getStudents)
//adding new student
router.post('/', createStudent)

export default router
```

controller-

```
  import StudentData from '../models/student_model.js'
    
    export const getStudents = async (req, res) => {
        try {
        const allStudents = await StudentData.find()
        res.status(200).json(allStudents)
            
    } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json( {message: err.message} )
    }};
    
    export const createStudent = async (req, res) => {
            const student = req.body
        const newStudent = new StudentData(student);
        try {
            await newStudent.save()
            res.status(201).json(newStudent)
            console.log('Student Created!')
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(404).json( {message: err.message})
            
        }
        
    }
```

model-

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

//model variable names must match the frontend useState's variables
const studentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    regNo: Number,
    sutdentName: String,
    grade: String,
    section: {
        type: Number,
        default: 'A'
    },
    subjects: [String]

})

const StudentData = mongoose.model('StudentData', studentSchema)
export default StudentData
```

form to create student-

```
import * as React from "react";
import {useState} from 'react'
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import axios from 'axios'

export default function CreateStudent() {
    //state hook to dynamically update displayed data
    const [student, setStudent] = useState({
        regNo: '',
        studentName: '',
        grade: '',
        section: ''
    })

    //using axios to transfer data from front to backend
    const createStudent = () => {
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/students', student)
        console.log(`  ${student.studentName}`)
    }
    return (
        
      <>
        <h2>Create New Student</h2>
        <Box
          component="form"
          sx={{
            "& > :not(style)": { m: 1, width: "25ch" },
          }}
          noValidate
          autoComplete="off"
        >
                <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Registration No." variant="outlined" value={student.regNo} onChange={(event) => {
                    setStudent({ ...student, regNo: event.target.value })
                }} />
                <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Name" variant="outlined" value={student.studentName} onChange={(event) => {
                    setStudent({ ...student, studentName: event.target.value })
                }} />
                <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Grade" variant="outlined" value={student.grade} onChange={(event) => {
                    setStudent({ ...student, grade: event.target.value })
                }}/>
                <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Class Section" variant="outlined" value={student.section} onChange={(event) => {
                    setStudent({ ...student, section: event.target.value })
                }}/>

          <Button variant="contained" onClick = {createStudent}>Submit</Button>
        </Box>
      </>
    );
}
```

Thank you in advance to anyone who lends a hand!

Comment: did you try making createStudent async and await axios.post

Comment: @cmgchess tried it with & without. shouldn't be an issue though as there aren't dependent methods after. leaving in the async though for best practices. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your middlewares are in the wrong order:

```
//middleware to use routes 
app.use('/students' , studentRoutes)

app.use(express.json())
```

The JSON body parser was mounted after the router. When a request reaches the route handler, the `req.body` will still be `undefined` because the body-parser has not parsed the JSON request body yet. Move the JSON body parser before the router.

Comment: Seems my earlier comment didn't go through. Thanks! That's all it was

Answer (score 0):

app.use(express.json()) should be above your routes.
Because when you make post request you work with json data and it requires
body parser to parse that json data so just take that line above your all routes.